# How do I select a List from something like new Dictionary(int, List<Customer>);

Tags: c#, linq

```
Dictionary<int, List<Customer>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Customer>>();
```

I want to query based on the key and get a List back.  Not sure how to structure the LINQ query for that.

Desired Output:

A `List<Customer>` for a particular key in the Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what the Dictionary (as you've defined the generic arguments) will do.  So, `dictionary[key]` will return the list.  Note that it will throw an exception if you haven't initialized it already with `dictionary[key] = new List<Customer>();`.

Comment: Seems like OP wants the answer using LINQ? Surely not this simple.

Comment: @Steve, I suppose, but forcibly using LINQ to exercise the native semantics of a Dictionary seems bizarre.

Comment: yeah, it was this simple.  Was doing LINQ to further par down the List and getting myself confused for a moment.  This works.

Comment: /Shane - agreed - nice when it's a simple answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use LINQ for this, but if you really want to

```
int key = 1;
List<Customer> customers = dictionary.Single(item => item.Key == key).Value;
```

The simplest way is to just retrieve the value for the key using the regular [] operator

```
dictionary[key];
```

Comment: this syntax would helpful in the future too, as i'm going to be doing a lot of Dictionary operations.  Thanks!